# How to change Gantt Chart data based on date selected

Tags: javascript, html, fusioncharts, gantt-chart

I want to change Gantt Chart data based on date selected in the date (dd:mm:yyyy) picker.

Here is my Screenshot.
[Gantt Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMHou.png)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8" ng-controller="ReportsController">
<div class="col-sm-12 page-top-actions">
    <div class="col-sm-3 day-wise-report">
      <input type="date" name="report" tooltip="Day">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 show-report">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Show Report</button>
    </div>
</div>
<select ng-init="selectedChart.chart = chartOptions[0]; updateChart()" ng-model="selectedChart.chart"
        ng-change="updateChart()" ng-options="c.name for c in chartOptions track by c.id"></select>
<fusioncharts
        id="exampleId"
        width="800"
        height="400"
        type="gantt"
        datasource="{{productivityReportData}}">
</fusioncharts>
```

Javascript Code:

```
    app.controller('ReportsController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.chartOptions = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Day 1"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Day 2"
    }];

    $scope.reportsDataSource = {

        "chart": {
            "dateformat": "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
            "outputDateFormat": "ddds mn    l, yyyy hh12:mn ampm",
            "caption": "Operator Productivity",
            "subCaption": "Day 1",
            "slackFillColor": "f44336",
            "showSlackAsFill": "1",
            "canvasBorderAlpha": "30",
            "plottooltext": "$processName{br} $label: starting time $start{br} - ending time $end",
            "theme": "fint"
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "category": [
                    {
                        "start": "09:00:00",
                        "end": "18:00:00",
                        "label": "Activity Timeline"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "align": "center",
                "category": [
                    {
                        "start": "11:00:00",
                        "end": "10:59:59",
                        "label": "9am-11am"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "11:00:00",
                        "end": "12:59:59",
                        "label": "11am-1pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "13:00:00",
                        "end": "13:59:59",
                        "label": "1pm-2pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "14:00:00",
                        "end": "15:59:59",
                        "label": "2pm-4pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "16:00:00",
                        "end": "17:59:59",
                        "label": "4pm-6pm"
                    }

                ]
            }
        ],
        "processes": {
            "fontsize": "12",
            "isbold": "1",
            "align": "left",
            "headertext": "Operators",
            "headerfontsize": "14",
            "headervalign": "middle",
            "headeralign": "left",
            "process": [
                {
                    "label": "Karthik",
                    "id": "EMP121"
                },
                {
                    "label": "David.G",
                    "id": "EMP122"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Mary.P",
                    "id": "EMP123"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Andrew.H",
                    "id": "EMP124"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Neil.M",
                    "id": "EMP125"
                }
            ]
        },
        "tasks": {
            "showlabels": "1",
            "task": [
                {
                    "processid": "EMP121",
                    "start": "09:00:00",
                    "end": "10:00:00",
                    "label": "Activity1"


                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP121",
                    "start": "15:00:00",
                    "end": "14:30:00",
                    "label": "Activity2"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP122",
                    "start": "10:00:00",
                    "end": "16:34:17",
                    "percentComplete": "75",
                    "label": "Activity3"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP123",
                    "start": "11:00:00",
                    "end": "12:10:00",
                    "label": "Activity4"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP123",
                    "start": "15:00:00",
                    "end": "17:32:00",
                    "label": "Activity 2"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP124",
                    "start": "10:30:00",
                    "end": "12:36:00",
                    "label": "Activity 2"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP125",
                    "start": "14:00:00",
                    "end": "15:32:00",
                    "label": "Activity 1"
                }
            ]
        }

    };
    $scope.reportsDataSource2 = {

        "chart": {
            "dateformat": "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
            "outputDateFormat": "ddds mnl, yyyy hh12:mn ampm",
            "caption": "Operator Productivity",
            "subCaption": "Day 2",
            "slackFillColor": "f44336",
            "showSlackAsFill": "1",
            "canvasBorderAlpha": "30",
            "plottooltext": "$processName{br} $label: starting time $start{br} - ending time $end",
            "theme": "fint"
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "category": [
                    {
                        "start": "09:00:00",
                        "end": "18:00:00",
                        "label": "Activity Timeline"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "align": "center",
                "category": [
                    {
                        "start": "09:00:00",
                        "end": "10:59:59",
                        "label": "9am-11am"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "11:00:00",
                        "end": "12:59:59",
                        "label": "11am-1pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "13:00:00",
                        "end": "13:59:59",
                        "label": "1pm-2pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "14:00:00",
                        "end": "15:59:59",
                        "label": "2pm-4pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "16:00:00",
                        "end": "17:59:59",
                        "label": "4pm-6pm"
                    }

                ]
            }
        ],
        "processes": {
            "fontsize": "12",
            "isbold": "1",
            "align": "left",
            "headertext": "Operators",
            "headerfontsize": "14",
            "headervalign": "middle",
            "headeralign": "left",
            "process": [
                {
                    "label": "Karthik",
                    "id": "EMP121"
                },
                {
                    "label": "David.G",
                    "id": "EMP122"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Mary.P",
                    "id": "EMP123"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Andrew.H",
                    "id": "EMP124"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Neil.M",
                    "id": "EMP125"
                }
            ]
        },
        "tasks": {
            "showlabels": "1",
            "task": [
                {
                    "processid": "EMP121",
                    "start": "09:00:00",
                    "end": "10:00:00",
                    "label": "Activity1"


                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP121",
                    "start": "15:00:00",
                    "end": "14:30:00",
                    "label": "Activity2"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP122",
                    "start": "10:00:00",
                    "end": "16:34:17",
                    "percentComplete": "75",
                    "label": "Activity3"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP123",
                    "start": "11:00:00",
                    "end": "12:10:00",
                    "label": "Activity4"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP123",
                    "start": "15:00:00",
                    "end": "17:32:00",
                    "label": "Activity 2"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP124",
                    "start": "10:30:00",
                    "end": "12:36:00",
                    "label": "Activity 2"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP125",
                    "start": "14:00:00",
                    "end": "15:32:00",
                    "label": "Activity 1"
                }
            ]
        }

    };
    $scope.updateChart = function () {

        if ($scope.selectedChart.chart === undefined || $scope.selectedChart.chart.id === 1) {
            $scope.productivityReportData = $scope.reportsDataSource;
        }

        if ($scope.selectedChart.chart !== undefined && $scope.selectedChart.chart.id === 2) {
            $scope.productivityReportData = $scope.reportsDataSource2;
        }
    };

}]);
```

Please, let me know how to integrate with HTML and generate data for the date, month and year selected.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the chart on selection of a date you gotta add eventlistener to `<input type="date" name="report" tooltip="Day"></div>`. 
I have changed your code a bit and updated the code.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ng-fusioncharts"]),
 globalContainer = {},
 _intUpdate;

app.controller('ReportsController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.chartOptions = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Day 1"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "Day 2"
    }];

    $scope.reportsDataSource = {

        "chart": {
            "dateformat": "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
            "outputDateFormat": "ddds mn    l, yyyy hh12:mn ampm",
            "caption": "Operator Productivity",
            "subCaption": "Day 1",
            "slackFillColor": "f44336",
            "showSlackAsFill": "1",
            "canvasBorderAlpha": "30",
            "plottooltext": "$processName{br} $label: starting time $start{br} - ending time $end",
            "theme": "fint"
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "category": [
                    {
                        "start": "09:00:00",
                        "end": "18:00:00",
                        "label": "Activity Timeline"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "align": "center",
                "category": [
                    {
                        "start": "11:00:00",
                        "end": "10:59:59",
                        "label": "9am-11am"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "11:00:00",
                        "end": "12:59:59",
                        "label": "11am-1pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "13:00:00",
                        "end": "13:59:59",
                        "label": "1pm-2pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "14:00:00",
                        "end": "15:59:59",
                        "label": "2pm-4pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "16:00:00",
                        "end": "17:59:59",
                        "label": "4pm-6pm"
                    }

                ]
            }
        ],
        "processes": {
            "fontsize": "12",
            "isbold": "1",
            "align": "left",
            "headertext": "Operators",
            "headerfontsize": "14",
            "headervalign": "middle",
            "headeralign": "left",
            "process": [
                {
                    "label": "Karthik",
                    "id": "EMP121"
                },
                {
                    "label": "David.G",
                    "id": "EMP122"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Mary.P",
                    "id": "EMP123"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Andrew.H",
                    "id": "EMP124"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Neil.M",
                    "id": "EMP125"
                }
            ]
        },
        "tasks": {
            "showlabels": "1",
            "task": [
                {
                    "processid": "EMP121",
                    "start": "09:00:00",
                    "end": "10:00:00",
                    "label": "Activity1"


                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP121",
                    "start": "15:00:00",
                    "end": "14:30:00",
                    "label": "Activity2"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP122",
                    "start": "10:00:00",
                    "end": "16:34:17",
                    "percentComplete": "75",
                    "label": "Activity3"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP123",
                    "start": "11:00:00",
                    "end": "12:10:00",
                    "label": "Activity4"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP123",
                    "start": "15:00:00",
                    "end": "17:32:00",
                    "label": "Activity 2"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP124",
                    "start": "10:30:00",
                    "end": "12:36:00",
                    "label": "Activity 2"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP125",
                    "start": "14:00:00",
                    "end": "15:32:00",
                    "label": "Activity 1"
                }
            ]
        }

    };
    $scope.reportsDataSource2 = {

        "chart": {
            "dateformat": "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",
            "outputDateFormat": "ddds mnl, yyyy hh12:mn ampm",
            "caption": "Operator Productivity",
            "subCaption": "Day 2",
            "slackFillColor": "f44336",
            "showSlackAsFill": "1",
            "canvasBorderAlpha": "30",
            "plottooltext": "$processName{br} $label: starting time $start{br} - ending time $end",
            "theme": "fint"
        },
        "categories": [
            {
                "category": [
                    {
                        "start": "09:00:00",
                        "end": "18:00:00",
                        "label": "Activity Timeline"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "align": "center",
                "category": [
                    {
                        "start": "09:00:00",
                        "end": "10:59:59",
                        "label": "9am-11am"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "11:00:00",
                        "end": "12:59:59",
                        "label": "11am-1pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "13:00:00",
                        "end": "13:59:59",
                        "label": "1pm-2pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "14:00:00",
                        "end": "15:59:59",
                        "label": "2pm-4pm"
                    },
                    {
                        "start": "16:00:00",
                        "end": "17:59:59",
                        "label": "4pm-6pm"
                    }

                ]
            }
        ],
        "processes": {
            "fontsize": "12",
            "isbold": "1",
            "align": "left",
            "headertext": "Operators",
            "headerfontsize": "14",
            "headervalign": "middle",
            "headeralign": "left",
            "process": [
                {
                    "label": "Karthik",
                    "id": "EMP121"
                },
                {
                    "label": "David.G",
                    "id": "EMP122"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Mary.P",
                    "id": "EMP123"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Andrew.H",
                    "id": "EMP124"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Neil.M",
                    "id": "EMP125"
                }
            ]
        },
        "tasks": {
            "showlabels": "1",
            "task": [
                {
                    "processid": "EMP121",
                    "start": "09:00:00",
                    "end": "10:00:00",
                    "label": "Activity1"


                },
                
                {
                    "processid": "EMP122",
                    "start": "10:00:00",
                    "end": "16:34:17",
                    "percentComplete": "75",
                    "label": "Activity3"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP123",
                    "start": "11:00:00",
                    "end": "12:10:00",
                    "label": "Activity4"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP123",
                    "start": "15:00:00",
                    "end": "17:32:00",
                    "label": "Activity 2"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP124",
                    "start": "10:30:00",
                    "end": "12:36:00",
                    "label": "Activity 2"
                },
                {
                    "processid": "EMP125",
                    "start": "14:00:00",
                    "end": "15:32:00",
                    "label": "Activity 1"
                }
            ]
        }

    };
    $scope.updateChart = function () {

        if ($scope.selectedChart.chart === undefined || $scope.selectedChart.chart.id === 1) {
            $scope.productivityReportData = $scope.reportsDataSource;
        }

        if ($scope.selectedChart.chart !== undefined && $scope.selectedChart.chart.id === 2) {
            $scope.productivityReportData = $scope.reportsDataSource2;
        }
    };

    $scope._intUpdate = _intUpdate = function(){
     $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.productivityReportData = $scope.reportsDataSource2; 
  }); 
    }

}]);

function updateChart(){
 _intUpdate();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
 <script src="http://fusioncharts.github.io/angular-fusioncharts/demos/js/angular-fusioncharts.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="col-sm-8" ng-controller="ReportsController">
 <div class="col-sm-12 page-top-actions">
     <div class="col-sm-3 day-wise-report">
       <input type="date" name="report" tooltip="Day" onchange="updateChart()">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3 show-report">
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Show Report</button>
     </div>
 </div>
 <select ng-init="selectedChart.chart = chartOptions[0]; updateChart()" ng-model="selectedChart.chart"
         ng-change="updateChart()" ng-options="c.name for c in chartOptions track by c.id"></select>

 <div fusioncharts
         id="exampleId"
         width="800"
         height="400"
         type="gantt"
         datasource="{{productivityReportData}}">
 </div>
</div>
```